# Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect ] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, gradle

I am new in Spring Application with Gradle.
Running my project to create the database objects based on my classes created, i got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect ] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1572)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:960)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:749)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:117)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:689)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:969)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:958)
at com.krypton.smartImmo.SmartImmoApplication.main(SmartImmoApplication.java:10)

Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect ] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:128)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:155)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:136)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:78)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:68)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:165)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
```

in the **application.properties** i ahve the following setting concerning hibernate

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Comment: Which version of hibernate are you on?

Comment: @GergelyBacso version 4.3.11.Final

Comment: I think you added a space after "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" ....? I see the blank in the stacktrace "[org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect ]"

Comment: I just wish to note it here that I was facing the same issue and my issue was not because of spacing or anything as such, my issue got resolved when I used **MySQL8Dialect** instead of **MysqlnnoDBDialect**

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Since you errormessage contains that suspicious extra space at the end:

```
Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect ]
```

I will take a wild guess that you have an extra space at the end of your dialect property.

So look for

```
"org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect "
```

and change it to:

```
"org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"
```

Comment: yes you are right didn't know this could be a root of an error :). Happy to learn that

Comment: The most common mistakes are normally either using a dialect that is not added to that specific hibernate release yet, or funny typos mostly with upper-case/lower-case letter mistakes.

Comment: How could I have had the exact same problem?  Heck, 38 of us did.  Crazy!

Answer (score 20):

I also faced the same issue, no need to declare any dialect in the properties file, after removing dialect properties, it work's fine.

My dependencies:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.7</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.7</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Application properties:
[image]

```
spring.datasource.name =test
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.deialect.MySql5InnoDBDialect
#spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.deialect.MySql55Dialect
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
##spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=updates`
```

Comment: Hi, I am using spring boot version 3.0.1 and on removal of the dialect it worked thank you.

Comment: Yes, it works after removing the dialect property.

Comment: Same for me, Spring Boot 3.0.1, removing the dialect works.

Comment: I am using version 3.1.0 and I get: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'javax.persistence.jdbc.url', 'hibernate.connection.url', or 'hibernate.dialect')

Answer (score 15):

[Solved 2023] I am using MySQL'8' so I simply changed it to *MySQL8Dialect*

> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect

So please check your MySQL Version and it will work fine

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. It saved me when I was about to give up on the error. Since `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect` was deprecated, I advise you to update it to `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect`.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using spring boot version above than 3.0.1, then please remove the dialect configuration from your application.properties file altogether. Spring boot does it for you.

Comment: I am using version 3.1.0 and I get: 
Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'javax.persistence.jdbc.url', 'hibernate.connection.url', or 'hibernate.dialect')

Comment: THANKS.... after removing spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect from properties file , its working

Answer (score 5):

Actually space is not the problem if your dialect name is correct.
But as **Rajiv Mishra** said, you don't need to explicitly specify the dialect, springboot does it for you automatically.

I am using STS ide for this.
[image]

Comment: Do you have a working example that includes a space at the end of the dialect property ?

Comment: Thanks, removing the property altogether worked.!

Comment: I am using version 3.1.0 and I get: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'javax.persistence.jdbc.url', 'hibernate.connection.url', or 'hibernate.dialect')

Answer (score 3):

My MySQL version was 8.1 so I tried `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect` it worked but
MySQL8Dialect has been deprecated;
use
`org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect` instead

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I too had the same problem of extra space. Just we have to make sure that, whenever we click on different lines in app.properties file , the cursor should be at the end ,just beside letter t of MySQL8Dialect.Enclose the value for the key spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect with " " quotes and then remove it, that way I had to resolve the issue, as cursor was not coming just after the letter t.

Comment: Please rephrase to make this more obviously an answer and seem less of a description of your own problem.

Comment: I too had the same problem with the dialect org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect  and I replaced it with org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect. It is working now for me. Venkat.